# How to start an activity when screen is turn on in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, background, broadcastreceiver, screen

When the device screen is turned on, I need to a start new `Activity`. It works properly on the emulator, but when when I run it on a physical device it doesn't work. It may not be working due to the API level. What's wrong with my code?  What can I do now?

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Here is my `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class MyWork extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent();
            intent1.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
       
            Log.e("s", "Screen on");
        }

        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.e("s", "Off");
        }
    }
}
```

My `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MyWork myWork = new MyWork();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        Log.e("s", "Main Activity");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION");
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        registerReceiver(myWork, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myWork);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Activity being destroyed?

Comment: nope! sorry for my late reply

Comment: @Hasitha Thamaranga can you help with this question?

Comment: It would seem that the simplest explanation is that onDestroy is being called followed by onCreate with the saved instance state on the physical device. It could happen because "Don't Keep Activities" is turned ON in the developer settings or for some other reason. Can you add breakpoints or logging to those methods and see what happens.

Comment: I could recheck and discover that under API 26 it can work perfectly, but API 26 or above Mainactivity class can not be called. I can set log at onDestroy method but it not worked. I things problems arise for API. but how can I do now? I do not understand.  If you wish I can share my project link.

Comment: Hmm...Sure. Send me the link. I will take a quick look. Cheers.

Comment: project link: https://github.com/hadiuzzaman524/Dummy-project-with-BroadcastReceiver

Comment: What kind of device is it? It is working fine for me on Android 10 (API 29). 1. Start the app with "hello world" 2. Tap power button to turn screen OFF 3. Tap button to turn screen ON 4. Enter lock code 5. The app reappears with "hello world". 6.The breakpoint for the case "ACTION_SCREEN_ON" is triggered in MyWork.java. Is onCreate being called when the device screen is turned back ON?

Comment: I can test it Xiaomi redmi 5 devices with API 26. But in your case, it works perfectly which I needed. actually, I wish when the user presses the volume button a long time my app will open in the device background and do it task. For the testing purpose, it can do it separately. I can try it also, but in android new rules, API 26 or upper can't define implicit broadcast that's why I can't do it. Now how to implement those things I'm confused. ref:https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: I don't fully understand the requirements, but it sounds like you want to use is something called a Foreground Service. It can register for any of these events and continually run after the Activity is destroyed. But it will consume a lot of battery on the user's device.